# Is there any benefit to making a Makefile a dependency of one of its own rules?

Tags: makefile

I came across this in a Makefile the other day:

```
%.elf: $(OBJS) $(LDSCRIPT) Makefile
    $(Q)$(LD) -o $(*).elf $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

What is the use of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this rule is the "parent" of all your other rules (i.e. all your targets require this rule), having the Makefile itself as a dependency ensures that if `$(OBJS)` is ever modified, your targets will be relinked no matter the state of your `.elf` output, because the `Makefile`'s last modified date will have changed.

It's a bit like a self-repair mechanism.

Comment: It is also a bit if a nuisance if you need to edit the Makefile for others reasons.